# Titanium Studio + moment.js having different result in iOS and Android

Tags: android, ios, titanium, appcelerator, momentjs

I have a cross platform app built with titanium studio
The app is using moment.js and this is my problem

```
var moment = require('moment/moment');
var now = moment(); 
Ti.API.info(now);
```

The values I get on android and ios are different
android value = 947124100905
ios value = 1405398490825

The format is not the same as well as the length of the values
I need the android value to have the same format like the ios one

Thanks

Comment: i am not sure what `var now = moment();` responds with , local or UTC time. so please check the timezone in your device.

Comment: You should check the [docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/) there is moment.utc() funtion which gives UTC, AFAIK it will be constant in different devices.

Answer (score 0):

I manage to solve my problem. I did not realize that the andriod device's date and time settings I am using for testing was not configured properly. It was still dated Jan 2006, that would explain why the value was always lower.

Anyways if this may help others, this is how I got a hint on how to solve my issue

```
var dateNow = new Date();
Ti.API.info(dateNow);
var now = moment(dateNow);
```

ios     = 2014-07-15 09:00:58 +0000

android = Thu Jan 06 2000 15:34:57 GMT+0900 (JST)

This were the values that I got, the format is different but moment.js can work with that no problem. My issue was just that the android device date was still on January 6 2000